# How to measure if a value stayed same for a period of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm making a smart bicycle backlight with Raspberry Pi and a SenseHat on top of it.

I'm measuring the output values of the SenseHat's accelerometer. There are actually three values reported as x, y, z and what I'm trying to know is whether my bicycle has been stationary for let's say 15 seconds or more. So if these values have been staying the same for over 15 seconds I'll turn off the backlight. And then if they start changing and stay like that for over 15 seconds, I want it to engage and start functioning again.

So far I've implemented strobe effect that auto activates when the bicycle is in idle. A steering detection - I show arrow animations to left and right based on the object detection sensor i put near the handlebar. I also implemented a brake detection. Once the accelerometer detects the braking, i show full red light.

If you check the code, you can see it's a bit tricky since the whole thing is in while loop and I need to make this detection as an if condition and then add else below, put rest of my existing if conditions there (such as deacceleration or turning detection)

**So how do I make Python measure certain values for 15 seconds without using time.delay and do things based on whether they change or stay the same?**

```
while True:
    
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()
    
    x, y, z = sense.get_accelerometer_raw().values()
    x = round(x, 2)
    y = round(y, 2)
    z = round(z, 2)
    print("x=%s, y=%s, z=%s" % (x, y, z))
    
    input = ser.read() #serial input i'm getting from arduino, it tells me if my left or right steering sensors are triggerred.
    yon = input.decode("utf-8")
    int(yon)

    if (z > 0.20): #If deacceleration is detected
        fren() # brake function is called
    else: # if no breaking is detected...
        if (yon == "1"): #if left turn sensor triggered
            sag_ok() #show left turn animation on led matrix
        elif (yon =="2"): # if right turn sensor triggered
            sol_ok() #show right turn animation on led matrix
        else: #anything else
            strobe() #show strobe effect if nothing else is detected
```

Comment: ok, so I wasn't far off in my initial comment, then. 15 seconds is way too short for our traffic lights

Comment: Anyway, I got distracted by all the text. I think it's pretty verbose for a question and might benefit from being trimmed down a bit. But I'll start actually looking at the code now

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to keep track of the last time when motion (or non-motion) was detected. If it was more than 15 seconds ago, then turn off (on) the light.

Something like this:

```
from time import monotonic

TAIL_LIGHT_DELAY = 15

time_of_last_motion = monotinic()
time_of_last_stop = monotonic()

while True:
    now = monotonic()

    motion = (abs(x) > 0.2) or (abs(y) > 0.2) or (abs(z) > 0.2)

    if motion:
        time_of_last_motion = now

        if now - time_of_last_stop > TAIL_LIGHT_DELAY:
            turn_on_tail_light()

    else:
        time_of_last_stop = now

        if now - time_of_last_motion > TAIL_LIGHT_DELAY:
            turn_off_tail_light()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting this but my IDE throws: NameError: name 'motion' is not defined

Comment: @ÇağanÇelik, Sorry, it is a placeholder for you to put in code that determines if there is any motion.  Like abs(x) < 0.2 and abs(y) < 0.2 and abs(z) < 0.2 or whatever works for your sensors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of smaller things that need to be addressed first:

1. `input = ser.read()`. `input` is actually a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and shouldn't be used as a variable name
2. `int(yon)` does nothing. You may well convert it to an `int` but the result is lost because you don't assign the result back to a name
3. `if (z > 0.20)` and all your other `if` checks - the brackets actually do nothing here; you can drop them.

A bigger thing to address: That loop is going full-pelt on the CPU core for absolutely no reason. Thousands of times a second, constantly. You should introduce a `time.sleep` to reduce the load.

Given that, you can achieve your desired output with a mixture of a Boolean flag and a record of when the accelerometer last gave 0 values.

```
import time

import datetime as dt

last_zeros = None
countdown_started = False

while True:
    
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()
    
    x, y, z = sense.get_accelerometer_raw().values()
    x = round(x, 2)
    y = round(y, 2)
    z = round(z, 2)
    print("x=%s, y=%s, z=%s" % (x, y, z))
    
    if x == 0 and y == 0 and z == 0:
        if countdown_started:
            duration = (dt.datetime.utcnow() - last_zeros_time).total_seconds()
            if duration > 15:
                # Do something to turn the light off here
                continue
        else:
            countdown_started = True
            last_zeros_time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    else:
        countdown_started = False
        
    
    sensor_input = ser.read() 
    yon = sensor_input.decode("utf-8")
    
    if (z > 0.20): 
        fren() 
    else: 
        if (yon == "1"): 
            sag_ok() 
        elif (yon =="2"): 
            sol_ok() 
        else: 
            strobe() 
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention that we cannot base the code on 0 value for the x,y,z. Because if the user parks the bike by dropping it on the ground or leaning it to an object, then the acceleromenter will give us different values like x=0.50, y=0.80, z=0.10. So the countdown won't start.

It's the stillness of those values that should trigger the countdown.

Comment: @ÇağanÇelik Sure, so set a threshold and change the `==` to `<= threshold_value`. I'd already anticipated this tbh but dropping the bike is still a pretty quick event - it's not as though it takes hours to fall over unless you're on some obscure tiny moon somewhere

Comment: It's not possible set a threshold. Let me explain, for instance if you drop the bike, x value KEEPS giving maximum lowest possible value as long as it is kept at that position. User may put the bike on some uneven terrain or leave it at some awkward position and the accelerometer keeps giving those numbers as long as the bike is in that position. And it is not possible to anticipate this and exclude. 

I think i understand your reasoning though. You believe the accelerometer would only show acceleration as x,y,z. This one reports acceleration + position of itself in the space. :/

Comment: @ÇağanÇelik in what frame of reference? Is it using GPS? There's something you're missing out here because you can't record `x`, `y` and `z` without some reference point if the object is stationary

Comment: Sensehat has IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) inside. It not only reports the acceleration to any direction, but also position of itself in space. X,Y,Z values change based on the position you put it. If you put it vertical for example the y value gets changed and stays like that until you put it back horizontal. y value also responds and changes based how much g force you apply (how much you accelerate it) towards that direction.

So x,y,z values both report acceleration and position information.

Comment: I cannot program it by supposing "if x,y and z are between certain values, consider the bicycle still." the user can place the bike upside down or lay it down and that would surpass my thresholds.

Comment: What I need is a way to know whether x,y and z are unchanged for 15 seconds or not. This is unrelated to what values x,y,z holds. I hope I could convey the idea with my limited English.